# Best way to create a conditional SQL query? CASE, DECODE, or IF/THEN?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case, decode

I am trying to make part of this query conditional, but I am really struggling to do so. Below I've typed out some pseudo-code that is representative of my query.

**Main Query**

```
SELECT A.T_NBR
,A.I_NBR
,A.DATE
,A.MX_CD
,A.MY_CD
,A.S_CD
,B.O_NBR
FROM A,B,C,D,E,F,H,I,TMP_J
WHERE A.MY_CD IN ('FOO','BAR')
AND A.T_NBR NOT IN (
   SELECT A.T_NBR
   FROM A,K
   WHERE A.MY_CD = 'BAR'
   AND P_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36)
   AND A.S_CD NOT IN ('AAA','BBB')
   AND K.K_CD NOT IN ('DDD','EEE')
   --JOIN
   AND A.I_NBR = K.I_NBR(+)
)
AND U_CD = 'FFFF'
--DATE LESS THAN 3 YEARS
AND TO_DATE(H.DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36)
--NUM GREATER THAN 23 
AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'SYYYY')-TO_CHAR(I.NUM,'SYYYY') > 23
AND A.S_CD NOT IN ('AAA','BBB')
AND B.DATE = (
   SELECT MAX(DATE)
   FROM B
)
AND B.O_NBR < 200
AND F.MG_CD <> '000'
AND A.T_NBR NOT IN (12345,54321,98765)
AND ((E.T IS NULL) OR (RTRIM(E.T) LIKE '%###%'))
AND TMP_J.I_NBR IS NULL
--JOINS
AND A.T_BR = B.T_NBR(+)
AND ((B.I_NBR = F.I_NBR) AND (B.DATE = F.DATE))
AND A.S_NBR = D.S_NBR(+)
AND A.D_NBR = C.D_NBR(+)
AND ((D.S_NBR = G.S_NBR(+)) AND (UPPER(G.A_CD(+)) = 'XXX'))
AND G.A_NBR = E.A_NBR(+)
AND H.I_NBR = A.I_NBR
AND A.S_NBR = I.S_NBR(+)
AND A.T_NBR = TMP_J.T_NBR(+);
```

Essentially, this is what I am trying to make conditional (written out in plain English with pseudo-code):

IF

```
A.MY_CD = 'BAR'
```

THEN

```
A.T_NBR NOT IN (
   SELECT A.T_NBR
   FROM A,K
   WHERE A.MY_CD = 'BAR'
   AND P_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36)
   AND A.S_CD NOT IN ('AAA','BBB')
   AND K.K_CD NOT IN ('DDD','EEE')
   --JOIN
   AND A.I_NBR = K.I_NBR(+)
)
```

ELSE IF

```
A.MY_CD = 'FOO'
```

THEN

```
WHERE U_CD = 'FFFF'
--DATE LESS THAN 3 YEARS
AND TO_DATE(H.DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36)
--NUM GREATER THAN 23 
AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'SYYYY')-TO_CHAR(I.NUM,'SYYYY') > 23
```

AND THEN I JUST WANT TO REST OF THE WHERE CLAUSES TO OPERATE OUTSIDE OF THE CONDITION.

Aside from not really knowing what method would work best (CASE/WHEN, DECODE, IF/THEN), the part where I'm really struggling is trying to implement a SELECT statement within these conditional clauses. I've tried implementing a CASE WHEN in the SELECT and WHERE parts of the query while attempting to put a SELECT statement in the WHEN portion of the CASE statement. I've also tried DECODE in the same fashion. Additionally, I have tried implementing an IF/THEN, but can't seem to tie it in with my main query.

I'm certainly not a pro when it comes to PL/SQL, so it may just be my lapse in knowledge. What would be the best approach to make a portion of this query conditional?

Thanks so much for your responses and assistance!

Comment: The "best" way is still building-up a query in a string using Dynamic SQL, which you then execute. This is because SQL itself does not support dynamic predicates (and I'm not aware of any vendor-extensions or attempts to build it either). I advise you to avoid hacks like `WHERE ( @paramA IS NULL OR colA= @paramA )` because they invariably mess-up the query-plan cache or index selection.

Comment: ...but I will grant you some tricks that (as far as I know) are harmless - such as "disabling" a predicate or term by setting the parameters to values that the DB engine safely elides as constant-elimination during the planning stage, such as in date-range queries. Another approach is to see if you can filter using a semi-join or anti-join instead of an equality-term - and so on...

Comment: The "good" way is to start using explicit `JOIN` clauses while avoiding to use `NOT IN` along with subqueries, you can rather prefer using `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan What problems do you see with `NOT IN`? Even if it's highly selective in a dataset for a query?

Comment: I have mostly encountered bad query performance(slow execution) for the queries with NOT IN followed subqueries. @Dai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to just want to combine the conditions with AND/OR logic; without making any other changes to your approach:

```
...
FROM A,B,C,D,E,F,H,I,TMP_J
WHERE
(
   (
      A.MY_CD = 'BAR'
      AND A.T_NBR NOT IN (
         SELECT A.T_NBR
         FROM A,K
         WHERE A.MY_CD = 'BAR'
         AND P_DATE < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36)
         AND A.S_CD NOT IN ('AAA','BBB')
         AND K.K_CD NOT IN ('DDD','EEE')
         --JOIN
         AND A.I_NBR = K.I_NBR(+)
      )
   )
   OR
   (
      A.MY_CD = 'FOO'
      AND U_CD = 'FFFF'
      --DATE LESS THAN 3 YEARS
      AND TO_DATE(H.DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -36)
      --NUM GREATER THAN 23 
      AND TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'SYYYY')-TO_CHAR(I.NUM,'SYYYY') > 23
   )
)
AND A.S_CD NOT IN ('AAA','BBB')
AND B.DATE = (
   SELECT MAX(DATE)
   FROM B
)
AND B.O_NBR < 200
AND F.MG_CD <> '000'
AND A.T_NBR NOT IN (12345,54321,98765)
AND ((E.T IS NULL) OR (RTRIM(E.T) LIKE '%###%'))
AND TMP_J.I_NBR IS NULL
--JOINS
...
```

That seems to be logically what you are asking for. But you will need to look at the execution plan and performance, among other things. There are various other issues to think about, including switching to use explicit joins, `not in` vs `not exists` (as mentioned in comments), not storing dates as strings, maybe using (more, modern) joins instead of subqueries, maybe using `extract()` to get your year number instead of `to_char()` and implicit conversion to a number (if that clause even makes sense), etc.

Comment: Thank you sir! This is what I was looking for, I was just overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would think about it:

```
IF A = X
THEN 
  IF B = Y
    CASE 1
  ELSE
    CASE 2
ELSE 
  IF C = Z
    CASE 3
```

Can be rewritten as

```
 IF (A = X) AND (B = Y)
   CASE 1

 IF (A = X) AND (B != Y)
   CASE 2

 IF (A != X) AND (C = Z)
   CASE 3
```

Which can be translated into a SQL WHERE statement like this:

```
 WHERE 
     -- Case 1
     ((A = X) AND (B = Y))  -- you can put more clauses using AND inside () 
   OR
     -- Case 2
     ((A = X) AND (B != Y)) -- you can put more clauses using AND inside () 
   OR
     -- Case 3
     ((A != X) AND (C = Z)) -- you can put more clauses using AND inside ()
```